# Firebase doesn't pick up email/password authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My code works perfectly, I get no errors, I've run the app through debug, nothing shows up. So I've already checked if I have the latest firebase dependencies and I've updated Google Play Services but for some reason My app won't register the user to Firebase.

```
EditText registerEmail, registerPassword;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    registerEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    registerPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    findViewById(R.id.registerButton).setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void registerUser() {
    String email = registerEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = registerPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(email.isEmpty()) {
        registerEmail.setError("Email is required");
        registerEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        registerEmail.setError("Enter a valid email");
        registerEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(password.isEmpty()) {
        registerPassword.setError("Password is required");
        registerPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(password.length() < 8) {
        registerPassword.setError("Minimum 8 characters required");
        registerPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.registerButton:
            registerUser();
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

            break;
        case R.id.loginTextView:

            startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));

            break;
    }
}
```

I get the "not successful" message so the issue must be in here somewhere  `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: add this line `task.getException().getMessage()` on your `else`

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira I got this: `W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = android.widget.LinearLayout{f150714 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #102039d android:id/toast_layout_root}
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null`

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Also this in Logcat: `W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.`

Comment: Please do not add your solution to your question. Instead, you can answer the question by clicking the "Answer Question" button below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you get are very misleading, and looking for a solution online I've found countless people struggling with this one but nobody mentioned **enabling Google Identity Toolkit API** which solved the issue for me.